# Parametric equations of a hypersurface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, geometry, coordinate-systems

In light-front QFT, in the Minkowski space, we define a hypersurface, $\Sigma_+ : x^3+ x^0 = 0 $. How can I write its parametric equations?

Comment: Would http://math.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I do think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way
\begin{align}
  X^0(\sigma^1, \sigma^2, \sigma^3) &= -\sigma^3 \\
  X^1(\sigma^1, \sigma^2, \sigma^3) &= \sigma^1 \\
  X^2(\sigma^1, \sigma^2, \sigma^3) &= \sigma^2 \\
  X^3(\sigma^1, \sigma^2, \sigma^3) &= \sigma^3 \\
\end{align}
where $(\sigma^1, \sigma^2,\sigma^3)\in\mathbb R^3$